# How do I know if I have the Northern Cities Vowel Shift?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels, accent

I grew up in Kalamazoo, MI, where (according to Wikipedia and other sources), many speakers have something called the [Northern Cities Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift) (NCS). So I'm trying to figure out if I'm one of them.

I'm running into two difficulties with this:

- The written descriptions of it all seem to be from the standpoint of, and written for, people who unambiguously don't have it; they'll say things like "they pronounce *job* like *jab*", meaning "NCS speakers' *job* is somewhere between non-NCS speakers' *job* and *jab*".
- According to everything I've read, one interesting difference between NCS and most other regional accents is that people from regions with NCS speakers don't notice the difference; NCS and non-NCS both sound the same to them. (And that's true of me; when I tried watching [a Youtube video of examples of NCS speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3noS_0IdrRo), I found that several of the examples sounded completely normal to me, but I certainly don't notice anything strange about non-NCS speech, either!)

So, how would I go about figuring this out?

Comment: Do you speak any other languages?

Comment: A fellow Michigander here would also like to know.

Comment: @phoog: Hebrew and French well, and a bit of Spanish. But I'm not sure if that'll help at all: English's vowel space is very different from any of theirs, so I think the difference between NCS and non-NCS Midwestern accents will be trivial by comparison. (Also, ideally I think an answer here should be useful to anyone else with the same question, whether or not they speak any other languages.)

Comment: I guess... there's [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/). Although it can be tricky to figure out how to do phonetic analysis, from what I understand vowels are the easiest phonemes to recognize. You could record yourself pronouncing various vowels and then see where the formants are.

Comment: That video is useless by itself. It gives no examples of people who don't have the accent.  How can one then identify which aspects of those people's speech define the accent? The video purports to show that these people don't speak like newscasters without giving examples of newscasters!

Comment: @phoog: Yeah, definitely. The video assumes that its viewers are non-NCS folks who will share its compiler's reaction to NCS -- which is the same problem I had with almost everything I've found on NCS. If you find anything better, please share. :-)

Comment: Do you know IPA? The Wikipedia article does a pretty good job, imo.  If you could say "bad" the same as an English person says "beard," that would be a pretty big sign.

Comment: @phoog: I *really* don't think I could say "bad" the same way an English person says "beard", but I *assume* that that's an exaggeration? I mean, are there NCS speakers who really pronounce "bad" all the way like English "beard"? (And -- I do know IPA in general, but the sounds are usually explained in terms of words they appear in, so if your accent doesn't match the guide . . .)

Comment: Apparently NCS speakers pronounce [*busses* as "bosses"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UoJ1-ZGb1w#t=01m41s) the clip shows the IPA, you can hear the standard North American pronunciation and compare it with the audio example. The YouTube video itself explains nicely the shift in pronunciation, how the o in "block" sounds like "black" to a listener who does not have the NCS accent.

Comment: Here's another YouTube clip showing the variations in vowel sounds across N America, including Canada. The /Scandinavian?) linguist gives the standard pronunciation of key words and then its modified version, so you can compare the two. https://youtu.be/d8WFuwRvvF4?t=4m35s From the same vid you can hear a [Michigan speaker](https://youtu.be/d8WFuwRvvF4?t=9m5s) and how he pronounces *bat*, *cot*, *caught*, *yes*, and *but*

Comment: I found the audio test which the first link talks about. Fun to hear and do! http://www.pbs.org/speak/ahead/change/vowelpower/vowel.html. If you don't make any "mistakes" in the transcription, you're probably a NCS speaker, I guess. I had to click on the hint link to "guess" the word, 4 out 5 correct. But without the hint, it would have been 0/5

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wow, great link! 3/5 with the hints,1/5 without them... adding to your theory that someone has to have the accent already to for those to seem "natural". And to Ruakh's surmise about the difference sounding trivial... I feel fairly comfortable in frequent business calls with the general midwest accent, but I'm willing to swear in writing that examples 2 and 5 of that link are inarticulate hoots and grunting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I haven't been able to do that test yet (I'll have to try it from another computer), but I expect I won't have any difficulty with it, since I come from a region with many NCS speakers. (For example, the non-NCS speaker at https://catapult.co/stories/behind-the-accent never noticed, growing up, that most of her neighbors had a different accent from her own. Obviously she would have noticed if she'd had difficulty understanding them!)

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to identify the words being uttered without hearing the hint, (which aren't easy either!) after submitting your answers the programme provides the answers with the complete phrases.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: OK, I stand corrected: I tried the quiz, and without listening to the hints, I got 1/5. ("Desk" sounded completely normal to me, though I would also consider that to be a completely normal pronunciation of "dusk". But the other four sounded crazy.) I really don't get it. How can this be a common accent in my hometown (supposedly), that I've never noticed, but that sounds so strange to me?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Oh, and -- thanks! Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @ruakh: your hometown may not have the most extreme version of the accent; I expect the quiz does. It's a vowel shift, and in some places with the NCS, the vowels will have shifted a lot farther than others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also born and raised in Kalamazoo, MI.  From my understanding of NCVS, I don't think I have it (can't entirely decide), but I'm sure my parents don't.

Considering my friend group of people who are from the cities (excluding suburbs) of Chicago, Detroit, and New York (the Bronx), I find NCVS:

- very noticeable from New Yorkers
- not at all noticeable from Detroit people
- somewhat noticeable from Chicagoans

Interesting, since Kalamazoo is the half-way point between Chicago/Detroit.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nenookaasi.  I grew up in the Detroit metro area and do notice a different pronunciation between people from Chicago and New York.  I do not *think* people in the lower peninsula have the pronunciation you describe.